# How can I upgrade my Samsung Galaxy S2 to the latest kernel?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have an SGS2 with Gingerbread 2.3.4 and kernel version `2.6.35.7-I9100XXKG1-CL349526 se.infra@SEP-39 #2`.

I heard that I can update the kernel to a newer version, but I have a few questions before I do it:

1. Which version should I update to?
2. What are the changes? Is there a change log ?
3. I'm using GO Launcher and have lots of apps installed. Should I back up these apps beforehand?

Comment: My sgs2 still have 2.3.3, and your kernel also seems newer than mine, maybe you already have latest version... Could you post a link to where you've learned that you can update?

Comment: @Smugrik http://androidadvices.com/update-samsung-galaxy-s2-gt-i9100-xxkg6-gingerbread-234-firmware/

But i really dont know what's newer XXKG6 or XXKH3...

Answer (score 1):

The version number come alphabetically, so a XXKH# is newer than XXKG#.

If you installed your apps from the market, they will be memorized and even installed back after update.

If your update comes through kies, just go ahead... But if its more complicated and you're not sure what it brings then why bother?

Comment: I heard it has better battery life, and Kernal update wont come from Kies it can only done manual..
So XXKH3 is the newest ?

Comment: Yes XXKH3 is newest.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to wait for the next big android update for SGS2. Its called Android 4 or "Ice Cream Sandwich". For the 15 biggest changes in ICS, you can take a look at [this website](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/10/19/android-ice-cream-sandwich_n_1019949.html#s420224&title=More_Camera_Features).
2. If you want to backup everything before a upgrade or reinstall, **use "MyBackup pro"**. You can get it [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5yZXJ3YXJlLmFuZHJvaWQuTXlCYWNrdXBQcm8iXQ).

Answer (score 0):

Get [Titanium Backup Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) before you experiment with kernels & ROMs. It's a paid app, but the best one for backup/restore of all your apps and settings.

You can wait for ICS as patchie says, or you can head to [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com) to look for custom ROMs and kernels.